# Using Selenium with Chrome won't load webpage

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is a strange bug regarding Selenium and Chrome. I've encountered a similar problem before but it's was temporary. But this keeps happening often.

The main problem, it was working fine a few days ago, then suddenly Chrome wouldn't load a webpage, I can load it regularly outside the script, but when I try to get it via Selenium, nothing.

I've tried a few things, such as adding additional options to Chrome, redownloading it.

> These are my options for Chrome

```
def browser_setup(self, headless=True):
        browser_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        browser_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
        if headless:
            browser_options.add_argument('--headless')
        browser_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
        browser_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        browser_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        browser_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
        browser_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=browser_options)
        return browser
```

One true solution I found for this problem is redownloading chrome driver, it fixes the issue, but after 2-3 runs, it return to the beginning and I need to redownload it again. I do not want to keep doing that, I couldn't locate the source of this issue, if someone had encountered and found a solution for it, it would be great.

Comment: can you paste the traceback you are getting or log files?

Comment: Well the error I am getting in the console, is regarding the script couldn't locate the element because the page wasn't loaded

Comment: have you tried loading other pages? also if problem persists you can try using firefox.

Comment: I tried and manually inserted URL and it loads with no problems, well I am not a big fan of Firefox, but if there isn't a good solution to this problem, it will be

Comment: By default when we launch the browser using Selenium, no extensions/addons will be added, also you are running headless, simply call it `options.setHeadless(true)`